# Validation issue using multiple Proc objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proc

I have validation with `Proc` and problem with it

```
validates :subcategory, presence: true, 
if: Proc.new {|product| product.detail.blank?} && Proc.new { |product|  product.category.id != 16 }
```

My problem is when i have `true` in second proc my validation fires.

Why is it so? Should it not return `false` because `false && true=>false`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have commented on better ways to implement what you want. I'll just point out the misunderstanding you have.

> it should return `false` because `false && true => false`

Nope. Actually, it's `Proc && Proc => Proc` (`proc1 && proc2 => proc2`). So your first proc is ignored due to how `&&` operator works (this happens at class loading time) and is never called, not even once.

Comment: and this would be a real answer the the question

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev Can you please explain how it is ignored at `class loading time`?

Comment: @Dinesh: that expression (`Proc && Proc`) is evaluated when file with that class is loaded. Since it's a part of `validates` call, which is a class-level expression. And yes, this means that `validates` is never called again either (since class is already loaded) (*I'm ignoring rails' dev mode class reloading here as irrelevant*).

Answer (score 5):

I think you'd be better of using single proc object:

```
validates :subcategory,
  presence: true,
  if: Proc.new { |product| product.detail.blank? && product.category.id != 16 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `product.category_id` be better, it won't blow up if there isn't a category and won't need to load the category from the db.

Comment: @j-dexx it would indeed, I just did not want to modify OP's code this much :)

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend using a method in :if.

```
validates :subcategory, presence: true, if: :my_cond?

def my_cond?
  detail.blank? && category.id != 16
end
```

It makes your code cleaner. if you figure out really good name for method `my_cond?` then your code will be more readable.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Yup.